# Can’t find a breaker

Tags: electrical

I have turned off every breaker in the panel. The light is still on. Now what?
Also I heard what sounded like a breaker popping. No breakers tripped. Different light doesn’t work.
Pulling my hair out.

Comment: If you have a main disconnect switch, turn that off and check if the light goes out.  Check for any GFCI's  for different light that doesn't work. Also. reset each breaker. Sometimes they can trip but it's hard to pick them out from being on.

Comment: Get a pen tester and make sure that every wire coming out of the electrical panel is actually dead when the breaker is shut off. Highly unlikely but you could have a faulty breaker.

Comment: What light are you talking about? A regular ceiling light?

Comment: Is it one of those bulbs with a battery built into it? https://www.amazon.com/Sengled-Emergency-Rechargeable-Battery-Equivalent/dp/B01H2TSJEU

Comment: Maybe the panel you are switching is actually a sub-panel, and your main panel with a few more breakers is somewhere else? Perhaps outside near the electric service entrance?

Comment: Is this light a garage door light?   Battery back up?

Comment: Basement bathroom light and separate outlet. None of the breakers are tripped.

Comment: I would go with a sub panel also, some feeders may come out of a panel attached to the meter. If on the same wall you may have heard the breaker trip through the wall.

Comment: If wires from the same leg separate breakers got connected together it would take two breakers to de-energize. If you turned breakers off only one off at a time then test again by leaving breakers off once turned off. If you finally reach a point that the circuit goes off leave the last breaker off and then go back to the top and turn breakers on until the circuit re-energizes.

Comment: Can you start at the meter and search for your main breaker that way, working down to the panel you know you have?

Comment: If the bathroom plug is affected and turning off all your breakers doesn't do it, you could plug a bitcoin miner in for a few months and ask your neighbour about his power bill.  Seriously though, are you in a stand alone structure or does it have multiple units?

Comment: Is this panel on the other side of the wall where your electric meter is. If not you have another panel somewhere.